# Automatically &nbsp; are inserted in page

Tags: html, angularjs, dom

Something is moving the content of the head in the body and inserting

```
&nbsp;
```

after every element.

[image]

Also removing everything in the page this happens:

[image]

Someone knows which is the problem here?

Comment: You need to provide more details

Comment: How is this html generated?

Comment: Are you doing an `ng-bind-html` in the `head`?

Comment: Where is your source code?

Comment: The website is stored in a virtual server LAMP, I inserted only the bootstrap folder inside, but this is also happened without bootstrap always in this virtual server

Comment: In the second example I removed every reference on Angular and jquery from the page but the problem is still there. It's a simple html page without javascript with a <title> in the header and a footer in the body

Comment: Ok SOLVED, it was because I copied and pasted some part of code from a website, within the code I also copied some hidden characters. I resolved using beautify in my editor.

Answer (score 0):

Ok SOLVED, it was because I copied and pasted some part of code from a website.
Within the code there were some hidden characters.

I resolved using *beautify* in my editor.